# How to show MPMoviePlayerController in landscape mode

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

i am working on a app where I am required to show "MPMoviePlayerController" in landscape mode and portrait mode. But My whole app is required to support Portrait mode only. That is no landscape mode for any view other than for the "MPMoviePlayerController".

I tried few things given over stack overflow. Nothing worked in my case. Feels Stuck in the middle. But I have seen some of the app supporting suck kind of requirements.
I have to implement it for both iOS 6, 7

In my app am using "XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController" for playing videos(playing the youtube videos)

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the following solved the problem:

First you need to allow the Landscape mode either, by checking the checkboxes at Target / General / Deployment Info / Device orientation, and then you have to disable Landscape orientation by code at every ViewController you use in your app.

```
#pragma mark - Set Supported Device Orientation

//For iOS6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

//For iOS4 and iOS5
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

But don't disable landscape orientation for the XCYoutubeVideoPlayerViewController, so at fullscreen it can rotate to landscape.

Comment: OK, Let me try this as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I just checked, that on few view controllers its working but on some its not. when I reach to the views that are using the TabBar Controller the code doesnt work and my views are able to rotate. Please Help

Comment: I have posted one more question for the same. Please Look

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179515/unable-to-stop-device-rotation

Comment: Insert the code above in the .m file of the navigation controller and tab bar controller as well.

Comment: @ttdaniI took them programatically inside the APPDELGATE class

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for this, It will work for all `MPMoviePlayerController`, below is my code

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)windowx
{
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]] ||
    [[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController")])
    {
        if ([self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController].isBeingDismissed)
        {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
        else
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

What we basically do here is we enable Landscape orientation for all `MPMoviePlayerController` classes which are actually `MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController` when you present it for fullscreen.

Hope this helps