# unable to stop device rotation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios6.1

I have posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172081/how-to-show-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-landscape-mode/23172764?noredirect=1#23172764) . In which one buddy replied and gave solution. Although the solution is working on few view controllers but on view its not working. When I enter a view controller that has TabController + navigation controller on there tab Bar Items, the code doesn't work. and the views are able to rotate.

I used the Following code for iOS 6.1

```
//For iOS6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I have to implement the same thing in iOS 7 too.
Please Help

Comment: What do you want? Stop rotation for all viewcontroller or stop rotation for a few viewcontroller?

Comment: @Rashad I want to disable rotation for all except one where I have to show MPMoviePlayerController in both landscape and portrait mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I m using a TabBarController, the only working solution I got was to create a category.

so just make a category

here's the .h class of the category, I named it AutoRotationtab

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface UITabBarController (AutoRotationTab)

@end
```

here's the .m class of the category

```
#import "UITabBarController+AutoRotationTab.h"

@implementation UITabBarController (AutoRotationTab)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
if(globalvariable_shouldRotate)
{
    return YES;
}
else
{
    return NO;
}
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

if(globalvariable_shouldRotate)
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
else
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
}
```

just make this category, and see the Magic, It works

Answer (score 2):

```
shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

The above methods don't get called of a `viewcontroller` if they are inside any `tabbarcontroller` of `navigationcontroller`. If these methods are declared inside `tabbarcontroller` or navigation controller then they will get called.

For solving this make a class `FixedOrientationTab`, it is a subclass of `UITabBarController`, and a navigation class `OrientationEnabledNavigation`, it is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. Then implemented `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods inside `FixedOrientationTab` and `OrientationEnabledNavigation`.

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation : UINavigationController

@end
```

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.m**

```
#import "OrientationEnabledNavigation.h"

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation ()

@end

@implementation OrientationEnabledNavigation

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
//    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FixedOrientationTab : UITabBarController

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.m**

```
#import "FixedOrientationTab.h"

@interface FixedOrientationTab ()

@end

@implementation FixedOrientationTab

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    //    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Then if you want to use navigation controller in your project then use `OrientationEnabledNavigation` and for tabbar `FixedOrientationTab`. After that if you implement `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` these method inside your `viewcontroller` then they will get called.

Hope this helps.. :)

**Edit**
As Jeev pointed out another way is that add some code beginning of your app delegate:

For `UITabBarController`

```
@implementation UITabBarController (AutoRotationForwarding)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)]) {
        return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

@end
```

For `UINavigationController`

```
@implementation UINavigationController (AutoRotationForwarding)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)]) {
        return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)])
    {
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed explanation. Let me check, I will get back in few minutes,,,Thanks again

Comment: I hv been in dvlpmnt from last 6 mnths,But I could'nt properly implement the method u mentioned above. Moreover I read some where that apple discards the idea of subclassing the UitabBarController.Then I moved.Then I found a soln of making category over http://www.kurutepe.com/2013/02/how-to-your-uitabbarcontrollers-and-uinavigationcontrollers-respect-your-auto-rotation-choices/

It worked perfectly for both iOS 6 and 7. The solution is very much similar to yours one. But I didn't create a Different UIatbarclass in my project, just made it inside the AppDelegate class...thanks a ton

Comment: Thanks. Thats why I love SO. Learned a new thing.. I am also gonna add this to my answer. It'll help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have UINavigationController contains UIViewController.

You should disable rotate in UINavigationController by subclass UINavigationController and implement

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
// return some
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
// return some thing that you want
}
```

Hope this helps you.